# Hyperparameter tuning on training data vs validation data

Tags: dataset, hyperparameter

If we divide the data into training data, validation data, and testing data, I remember the lesson from Andrew Ng saying we use the validation data for hyperparameter tuning purpose.
(you can see this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-do-we-need-a-validation-set-in-addition-to-training-and-test-sets-5cf4a65550e0)

My question is why not using training data for hyperparameter tuning since we have more data within?

Comment: What do you mean by using the training data for hyperparameter tuning?

Comment: Meaning find the best parameters for the model using training data (do prediction, find the parameters that gives lowest errors) @Dave

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of how this would go: what hyperparameter parameter would you aim to tune, and how would you tune it using only the training data?